# Vim spontaneously resizes and distorts windows after screen unlock

Tags: vim, neovim

When I lock the screen then unlock it again, the windows are resized and distorted. Unmaximizing then maximizing the terminal window restores the buffers then using `ctrl` + `w` + `=` fixes the windows size. I'm using neovim 0.1.7 on Debian Stretch with Gnome-Shell 3.22.3.

**Before screen lock:**
[image: Before screen lock]

**After screen unlock**:
[image: After screen unlock]

Answer (score -1):

First off, you should use the most recent version of Neovim, which at the moment is 0.2.2. You can easily build it from source or use the Ubuntu PPAs which should work on Debian: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#ubuntu

Additionally, I recommend adding the following autocmd to handle resizing gracefully:

```
autocmd VimResized * exe 'normal! \<c-w>='
```

Comment: I'm already using `ctrl + w + =` to restore the windows, but that's not a solution. I don't want the size to change in the first place

Comment: Yes, no difference

Comment: In this case, it's probably related to Gnome Shell, not Neovim. Have you tried another terminal emulator?

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same problem with terminator

Comment: Not a solution. It balances the windows, does not restore them to what they were before resizing.  This is clearly related somehow to X or gnome changing the screen size when it is locked (my best guess). I have only noticed this on 4K screens.  Trying to find more info online but not much exists!

Comment: This might be related to this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-gnome-meta/+bug/1726548/comments/31 (comment #31)